# Is it possible to syncronise a mysql database to bitbucket?

Tags: php, mysql, git, version-control, bitbucket

I have a php project which stores in bitbucket. But i didn't use git with database before. After a few research i started to think about that is my aim possible. I just want to store whole my project with php and mysql codes on bitbucket.

I tried several mysql migration tools such as "dbv, liquibase, jdk, etc." But i couldn't completely understand what's goin on with them.

Now i have these apps installed on my pc:
OS: Windows 10
Xampp Server: 3.2.2
Php: 5.6.23
Mysql: 4.5.1
Mysql WorkBench: 6.3

While i was searching for bitbucket and mysql i found these articles which says it's not possible as i understand.
On this article bitbucket says they don't support mysql databases: https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/supported-platforms-776640981.html

And on this the same result:
https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/connecting-bitbucket-server-to-mysql-776640382.html#ConnectingBitbucketServertoMySQL-create

So this is where my question appears. I just searching for the right applications to sync mysql database to bitbucket (or maybe github as last option).

Some people think that this is not a possible request on programming world. If you have the same idea please watch this video before answer:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pv13GpjGVmY&t=2s

Comment: Can you clarify a bit more what you want to achieve? Do you just want to store the database schema and some data, like backups, or are you asking for some type "live sync" with data on bitbucket?

Comment: I just want to commit and push my database to bitbucket same as php codes.

Comment: Do a mysql dump and upload it?

Comment: So the problem is that :) I don't know which way to follow. I just heart the name of mysql dump.

Comment: _"I just heart the name of mysql dump"_ - Then I would recommend that you read up on how it works and make some attempts. [Here's a post about mysqldump](https://www.linode.com/docs/databases/mysql/use-mysqldump-to-back-up-mysql-or-mariadb/). if you google on it, you will find many examples. There are a bunch of examples on this site as well.

Comment: Does "mysqldump" cover my question? For example i can syncronise my php codes with bitbucket from "Visual Studio Code". As my short research "mysqldump" seems like backing up a database so i need a command line to do that. After backing up i need to write new console commands such as commit and push. But while synronising my php codes i just use buttons on VSC. Some tips on youtube says that this can be make by Mysql Workbench or some tools like that.

Comment: So what you want/need is the one magic button to do it all?

Comment: Not a magic button! I'm looking for a program to do it all. In my less knowledge i figure a crazy solution which is "Setting up the localhost folder as base folder and ignoring the unnecessary stuff except htdocs and mysql/data folders." But this isn't a good way to do that i think. Certainly there are some people using some programs which i looking for. So I'm not typing a random question here. After 1 week research i need to help.

Comment: Version controlling databases is not particularly easy and the question regulwrly comes up here on SO. The problem is that here on SO asking us to recommend tools / utilities to perform any activities is explicitly off-topic and version controlling a database is something you really want to use a utility for.